# Complex restart of group of units within systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

My app consists of haproxy unit and 5 units of app itself (app@1, app@2, etc).

I have a bash script for restarting

```
systemctl reload hapoxy
echo "disable server myapp/app-1" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy-admin
systemctl restart 'app@1'
echo "enable server myapp/app-1" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy-admin
echo "disable server myapp/app-2" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy-admin
systemctl restart 'app@2'
echo "enable server myapp/app-2" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy-admin
...
cache warm-up
other stuff
```

But I'm wondering, is there a way to run restart through systemd?

P.S. I have myapp.target with those units and haproxy as a dependencies, but target files don't have a restart command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PartOf=`. From `man systemd.unit`:

> PartOf=
>              Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts
>   the units listed here, the
>              action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed
>   units.

So you can create a new unit file and then make all the things you want to restart together "PartOf=" this new unit. Then restarting the new unit will restart everything you want.

This topic is discussed more at [How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283714/how-to-create-a-virtual-systemd-service-to-stop-start-several-instances-together)

Comment: But what process will be the main pid of this "new unit file"?
I belive it is more appropriate to use target files for this kind of grouping (which don't have separate process), but target files do not have a restart command.
I can create a fake unit file, whith some process that is just infinite loop, but that feels wrong.

Comment: @KirillFuntov I agree target units are good for this, and `stop`, `start` and `restart` all work on them... I just tested `systemctl restart bluetooth.target` on my Ubuntu laptop. Did you find some documentation that says that restart does *not* work for targets?

Comment: stop, start and other stuff works on targets. But they limited to basically send stop, start or restart commands for their units. I see no way to execute custom script on restarting whole unit.